# Is it possible to change CSS Validation scheme in VS2010

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, editor

I'm editing a simple CSS file in VS2010 and the editor seems to have a rather limited understanding of CSS, for example:

```
#my-rule {
     position:relative;
}
```

generates a warning: `Validation(CSS 1.0): 'position' is not a known CSS property name`

I'm guessing that there is an option some where to change the CSS validation to CSS 2.1 or some thing close, but can't for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have a dropdown in the top menu where you can switch the css validation. It's called Cascading stylesheet version for validation. If you can't see it right click on the menu and check Style sheet so it will show.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i can get the Style Sheet menu, but 'CSS 3.0' is not one of my options. :( Quality MS programs at their best.

Answer (score 61):

If you want to validate for CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010, you need to install the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 and then install the "CSS 3 Intellisense Schema"

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Discussions

Then you will see "CSS 3.0" in the drop down that easwee mentioned.

Comment: I don't mention any css3 but ok :)

Comment: Yes, I added to your posted for anyone else that came across your question and was wondering how to get CSS 3.0 working in VS.NET 2010.