# Change doctype in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, doctype

I have tried to change the doctype from XHTML 1.0 to HTML5 doctype, by changing the doctype line in `Site.Master.cs`. However after the change HTML5 tags is still not recognized in Visual Studio 2010. Is there something more that I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Have you installed the [web standards update to VS 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83)?

Comment: I have installed updates that's been asked by the update manager only. Is it this update that you mean? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on the tool bar at the top and enable the 'HTML Source Editing' tool bar.

You should then be able to select the target schema for validation from the drop down.

[image]

**NOTE**: Ensure you are viewing the aspx page, the drop down is greyed out otherwsie

Comment: do you happen to know how to set CSS3 validation also? I can chose CSS2.1 or lower only it seems.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210 from the second answer on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931801/is-it-possible-to-change-css-validation-scheme-in-vs2010.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution that will work regardless of which type of page you're viewing:

Tools --> Options... --> Text Editor --> HTML --> Validation

Select the "Target:" from the dropdown that you'd like to use for validation.