# VS2010, HTML 5 and CSS 3 Validation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, css, intellisense

I want to switch CSS validation in VS2010 SP1 from CSS 2.1 to CSS 3.

I came across this answer:

[Is it possible to change CSS Validation scheme in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931801/is-it-possible-to-change-css-validation-scheme-in-vs2010)

What is not clear to me is how to activate CSS 3 validation.  I did find that switching HTML validation to HTML 5 causes CSS to be validated as CSS 3 (after installing [CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Discussions)).

However, I would have thought that the HTML level and the CSS level would be orthogonal.

Am I missing something, or does the HTML validation switch truly also control the CSS validation level?

Comment: "I did find that switching HTML validation to HTML 5 causes CSS to be validated as CSS 3" I find that strange too. Does VS2010 come with HTML5 validation out of the box though? I can't remember.

Comment: @BoldClock: I didn't do anything special to get HTML 5 validation, though I had installed SP1 before looking for that setting so not sure if it's pre-SP1 or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, right click on the toolbar in VS2010 and enable 'Style Sheet'. Then once a CSS file is open and has focus you can change the target CSS validator from the drop down.

[image]

Comment: But how can you select the CSS level for css inside a html or aspx file?