# Prevent VS2010 CSS Validation from Reverting to CSS 2.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

I validate CSS in my new projects against CSS 3.0, thanks to the solution here:

[VS2010, HTML 5 and CSS 3 Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572526/vs2010-html-5-and-css-3-validation)

However, every time I load the project, CSS validation reverts to 2.1 and has to be set through the toolbar to validate against 3.0 again.

Is there a way to make my selection sticky?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in Options -> Text Editor -> CSS Validation. I have taken the screenshot from VS2012. It is same in VS2010.

[image]

Comment: As a side Note, you will need VS2010 SP1 to use CSS 3 validation. Since you have been validating against, CSS 3. That means you already have it. :-)

Comment: I have 2010 Pro SP1 and I do not see this option, however I do see a Miscellaneous item, but that does not contain validation options.

Answer (score 1):

First, shut down VS2010

Assuming you're validating against html5 - the validation option is in

> Text Editor-->HTML-->Validation

Set it to **HTML5** validation. Then verify the following file exists:

> < your install directory >\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\html_5.xsd

Copy the file elsewhere to be safe then edit the original file using a text editor.  Near the top of the file find the string:

> vs:cssschema="CSS 2.1"

and change it to:

> vs:cssschema="CSS 3.0"

if it isn't already.  Then save the file and restart VS2010.  That should take care of making CSS 3.0 validation sticky against html5 projects