# using @font-face css in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am using @font-face in my css. Mine is an ASP.NET webapplication the doctype used for the page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The css is as follows

```
 @font-face                         { font-family: 'ML-TTLeela';
                                 src: url('../Styles/Font/mlll0ntt.eot') ;/* IE9 Compat Modes */
                                 src: url('../Styles/Font/mlll0ntt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
                                 url('../Styles/Font/mlll0ntt.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
                                 url('../Styles/Font/mlll0ntt.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
                                 url('../Styles/Font/mlll0ntt.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */ }
```

Am using VS 2010 and CSS is validated against CSS 2.1. how can i change it to CSS 3?
@font-face doesnot seems working too.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from: [Is it possible to change CSS Validation scheme in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931801/is-it-possible-to-change-css-validation-scheme-in-vs2010)

If you want to validate for CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010, you need to [install](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Discussions) the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 and then install the "CSS 3 Intellisense Schema"

Then you will see "CSS 3.0" in the drop down that easwee mentioned.