# Setting default CSS validation schema in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, resharper

After recently installing Resharper I started getting warnings where it was finding items in style sheets that were not compatible with CSS 3. I was receiving error messages such as:

```
'xxxx' is not a known CSS property name
Property 'xxxxx' doesn't exist in CSS 3.0
```

It seems that Visual Studio is set up to use CSS 2.1 validation.  I've found a questions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931801/is-it-possible-to-change-css-validation-scheme-in-vs2010) saying how to turn the validation on, but nothing saying how to set the schema validation version. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a UI for changing the schema version but it can be done manually.

Navigate to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\
```

There should be a file called `html_5.xsd` that contains the the setting.

Look for the `vs:cssschema` element (which should be near the top of the file) and change it from :

```
vs:cssschema="CSS 2.1"
```

to

```
vs:cssschema="CSS 3.0"
```

After re-starting Visual Studio the CSS schema validation version should change.

Comment: Still valid to VS2017!

Comment: Well not really - path in VS2017 (at least in my install) is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Packages\Schemas\html. My setting is 2.1, but VS is telling me my CSS isn't valid with CSS 4.0.  This validation is happening in my .less file; this setting may be only when styles are being defined in HTML.